# Windows could not start the Server service on Local Computer. Error 1068

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, dns, services

I am trying to start the Server service and the Computer Browser service at boot.  I believe the Computer Browser service relies on the server service to be running.  When I attempt to start either service it gives me the error: "Windows could not start the Server service on Local Computer. Error 1068: The dependency service or group failed to start."

I am attempting to make this computer discoverable as well as turn on file and printer sharing on its workgroup.  I successfully started these services:

```
o DHCP Client
o DNS Client
o Network Connections
o Network Location Awareness
o Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
o TCP/IP Netbios helper
o Workstation
```

Any assistance? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this:

Server service is dependent on Security Accounts Manager to be running, started that service allowed Server service to start which allowed for Computer Browser service to start.